# DropDownListFor post value NULL to database

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, razor

I have a Course Table and a Hole Table in SQL. There is a foreign Key in the hole Table that is set to the CourseId.

This is so that when I create a hole I can assign it to the relevant course.

In my View I have a dropdownlistfor that has a list of courses to select from when creating the hole. However when I try and post back the values the courseID does not post back.

HoleViewModel

```
 // GET: HoleViewModels/Create
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        var dbcourse = db.Course.ToList();

        //Make selectlist, which is IEnumerable<SelectListItem>
        var courseNameDropdownList = new SelectList(db.Course.Select(item => new SelectListItem()
        {
            Text = item.CourseName.ToString(),
            Value = item.CourseId.ToString()
        }).ToList(), "Value", "Text");

        // Assign the Selectlist to the View Model   
        var viewCourse = new HoleViewModel()
        {
            Course = dbcourse.FirstOrDefault(),
            // The Dropdownlist values
            CourseNamesDropdownList = courseNameDropdownList,

        };

        
        return View(viewCourse);
    }

    // POST: HoleViewModels/Create
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "HoleId,HoleNumber,Par,Length,StrokeIndex,CourseId")]  HoleViewModel holeViewModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.HoleViewModels.Add(holeViewModel);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        
        return View(holeViewModel);
    }
```

The Create.cshtml

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
```

{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

```
<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>HoleViewModel</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.HoleNumber, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.HoleNumber, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.HoleNumber, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Par, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Par, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Par, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Length, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Length, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Length, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.StrokeIndex, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.StrokeIndex, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StrokeIndex, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Course.CourseId, "CourseId", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Course.CourseId, Model.CourseNamesDropdownList, "Please select from List", new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CourseId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

So when the holeview posts back holeNumber, Par, Length, StrokeIndex, CourseID. it passes all data into the hole table other than the courseId which it posts a null.

What am I missing from the POST to get the CourseId to be entered in the Database.